# Conexion java y mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Algun duda de como solucionar el error? eso me aparece cuando intento realizar una grafica en Jfreechart. al parecer el error esta en el conector.

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class javaconnect {


     Connection conn = null;
    public static Connection ConnecrDb(){
       try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prueba1","root","marbella2011");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return ConnecrDb();
    }


}
```

El error que me sale es el siguiente.

> .mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: ""
>   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)

Comment: La pregunta esencial es: Tienes desplegado un Mysql en tu PC local por el puerto 3306 y que tenga una base de datos prueba1 con esas credenciales? Si es así prueba conectando a la BD con un cliente como HeidiSQL para que puedas ver si está recibiendo conexiones.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321182/mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-data-source-rejected-establishment-of-conn

Comment: @Deoxyseia el mensaje de error indica que la conexión ha sido rechazada (nótese la palabra **rejected**). Esto significa que la base de datos existe y se puede conectar mediante esa configuración pero que la base de datos rechaza la conexión, quizás (muy posiblemente, en mi opinión) porque ya no soporta más conexiones.

Answer (score 1):

Según la explicación realizada en preguntas similares en el sitio en inglés:

- [Data source rejected establishment of connection, message from server: “Too many connections”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5778002/1065197)
- [Error: Data source rejected establishment of connection, message from server: “Too many connections”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22604952/1065197)
- [Error: Data source rejected establishment of connection, message from server: “Too many connections”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24693760/1065197) (pregunta diferente a la del enlace anterior, aunque tienen el mismo título)

El problema parece ser que tu base de datos tiene demasiadas conexiones abiertas, por lo cual ya no puede abrir más conexiones. Puedes revisar las conexiones hechas a tu base de datos MySQL mediante el comando `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, puedes ir eliminando esas conexiones mediante el comando `KILL <processid>`, el `<processid>` lo obtienes como resultado del comando para ver las conexiones.

Ahora, este problema puede re aparecer debido a que no estás cerrando las conexiones en tu aplicación adecuadamente o porque tu base de datos está configurada para tener un número muy limitado de conexiones (dudo mucho de esto a menos que hayas estado jugando con las configuraciones de my.ini o my.cfg puesto que el valor por defecto en MySQL es de 150). Te recomiendo revisar tu aplicación y los lugares donde utilizas una conexión a base de datos para que la cierres apropiadamente llamando al método `Connection#close` **SIEMPRE** (consejo general para los lectores de esta respuesta).

En tu caso puntual, esto se debe a que tu método es recursivo e infinito, notado por este par de líneas:

```
public static Connection ConnecrDb() {
    //implementación no necesaria para evaluar que es recursivo infinito
    return ConnecrDb(); //retorna el resultado de llamarse a sí mismo
        //lo que resulta en una recursividad infinita puesto que
        //no hay restricciones para evitar este resultado
}
```

Tu código debería estar escrito de la siguiente manera:

```
public static Connection ConnecrDb(){
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        //desde Java 7 y JDBC 4 no necesitas llamar a esta línea
        //para abrir una conexión a la base de datos
        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prueba1","root","marbella2011");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //es mejor tener todo el stacktrace del error
        //no solo el mensaje
        //System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
    //return ConnecrDb();
    return conn;
}
```

Asimismo, de lo explicado anteriormente, recuerda **SIEMPRE** cerrar tus conexiones a base de datos, ya sea llamando al método `Connection#close` manualmente o utilizando `try-with-resources` disponible desde Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

1.- Crear una clase de tipo Java Inteface de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya que hemos creado la clase IConexion debemos de poner el siguiente codigo:

```
import java.sql.Connection;

public interface IConexion {
public Connection getConex();
public Connection establecerDB();
public void getClose();
```

}

Después de que hemos creado la interface continuamos a la clase conexión la clase a la que vamos a llamar ecConexionJRAVBSingleton esta clase la creamos de forma normal y continuamos a hacer los siguiente:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import mx.com.JRAlejandroV.IMetodos.IConexion;

public class ecConexionJRAVBSingleton implements IConexion{

private Connection con = null;
private static ecConexionJRAVBSingleton instancia;

private ecConexionJRAVBSingleton(){

}

public static ecConexionJRAVBSingleton obtenerInstancia(){
    if(instancia == null){
        instancia = new ecConexionJRAVBSingleton();
        System.out.println("Exito en conexion singleton");
    }
    return instancia;
}

@Override
public Connection getConex() {
    return establecerDB();
}

@Override
public Connection establecerDB() {
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String user = "root";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grupoautofinprueba";
        String password = "";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Driver no encontrado");
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Fallo al recibir base de datos");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay resultado");
    }finally{
        return con;
    }
}

@Override
public void getClose() {
    try{
        con.close();
    }catch(SQLException ex){

    }
}
```

}

Con esto podemos dar como exitosa la conexión a mysql desde java